# ConcurrentBag:System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object

Tags: c#

I have List of Dictionary Records,using that records converting into object and some applying logic on data from method "**CheckPropertyIsObjectorArrayOrDefault**"

and adding into "**ObjectList**".So after that finally ConcurrentBag ObjectList iterating using while loop but getting the following Exception.

> [12:30:16] [Error] (2) Exception :: System.ObjectDisposedException:
>   Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'The ThreadLocal object
>   has been disposed.'.    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadLocal`1.GetValueSlow()    at
>   myApp.Client.LoadTenantConfigCache(JObject tableObject, String
>   tenantId, String tenantName, String dbQuery) in
>   C:\code\v2\myApp\myApp\Client.cs:line 1147, Properties::
>   {"MethodName": "LoadTenantConfigCache()", "Payload": null,
>   "innerException": null, "MainException":
>   "System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed
>   object.\r\nObject name: 'The ThreadLocal object has been
>   disposed.'.\r\n   at System.Threading.ThreadLocal`1.GetValueSlow()\r\n
>   at myApp.Client.LoadTenantConfigCache(JObject tableObject, String
>   tenantId, String tenantName, String dbQuery) in
>   C:\code\v2\myApp\myApp\Client.cs:line 1147"} {"Environment":
>   "Production"}
>
> [12:30:16] [Error] (2) Exception :: System.ObjectDisposedException:
>   Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'The ThreadLocal object
>   has been disposed.'.    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadLocal`1.GetValueSlow()    at
>   myApp.Client.LoadTenantConfigCache(JObject tableObject, String
>   tenantId, String tenantName, String dbQuery) in
>   C:\code\v2\myApp\myApp\Client.cs:line 1147[TableName : Entities]
>   [Count: 30] , Properties:: {"MethodName": "LoadTenantConfigCache()",
>   "Payload": null, "innerException": null, "MainException":
>   "System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed
>   object.\r\nObject name: 'The ThreadLocal object has been
>   disposed.'.\r\n   at System.Threading.ThreadLocal`1.GetValueSlow()\r\n
>   at myApp.Client.LoadTenantConfigCache(JObject tableObject, String
>   tenantId, String tenantName, String dbQuery) in
>   C:\code\v2\myApp\myApp\Client.cs:line 1147"} {"Environment":
>   "Production"}

here is the code:

```
List<Dictionary<string, object>> objectList = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

    //adding data into objectList logic
     ...
     ...

    ConcurrentBag<JObject> parsedObjectList = new ConcurrentBag<JObject>();

    var tasks = new ConcurrentBag<Task>();
    foreach (var dictObject in objectList)
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(async (object entity) =>
         {
             JObject obj = new JObject();
             var res = "";
             var key = "";
             var column = "";
             Dictionary<string, object> data = (Dictionary<string, object>)entity;
             foreach (var readerObject in data)
             {           
                 key = readerObject.Key;
                 column = readerObject.Value.ToString();             
                 res = await _common.CheckPropertyIsObjectorArrayOrDefault(column, key, tableName, tempInstance, obj);       
             }
             if (res == "Success")
                 parsedObjectList.Add(obj);
             else
                 Console.WriteLine("Missing Records Key:" + key + " Value: " + column);
         }, state: dictObject);
        tasks.Add(task);
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    using (var ldr = Ignite.GetDataStreamer<string, ICustomCacheStore>(cacheName))
    {
        ldr.AutoFlushFrequency = 10;

        JObject item = null;
        while (parsedObjectList.TryTake(out item))//from here throwing error
        {       
            var tInstance = (ICustomCacheStore)Activator.CreateInstance(tempType);

            JObject keyObj = new JObject();
            foreach (var keyName in keyArray)
            {
                var pk = keyName.ToString();
                if (item.ContainsKey(pk))
                    keyObj[pk] = item[pk];
            }
            keyObj["TableName"] = tableName;

            //Create Instance For PrimarykeyModel
            var priKeyInstance = (IKeyModel)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(primaryKeyModel + ", Models"));
            var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore };

            //populate Object for Type Key
            JsonConvert.PopulateObject(keyObj.ToString(), priKeyInstance, serializerSettings);
            JsonConvert.PopulateObject(item.ToString(), tInstance, serializerSettings);
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(priKeyInstance, Formatting.None);

            string base64EncodedKey = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));

            await ldr.AddData(base64EncodedKey, tInstance);

        }
    }
```

What might be the cause behind this.Can any one suggest me to solve the Exception.

Thanks.

Comment: It's difficult to match up the errors you're showing with the code. We don't know which line is 1147. Can you indicate which line is throwing the exception, and which object is disposed? `while (parsedObjectList.TryTake(out item))` can't be it because `ConcurrentBag<T>` isn't disposable.

Comment: It's also unclear why you're creating a `Task` with an `async` method for something which isn't asynchronous. `var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(async (object entity) =>` There's also a massive amount of code not shown. The line number (1147, lots of lines) and the fact that the line you've commented as the source precedes any disposable objects strongly suggests that the problem either is or includes code that isn't shown.